# How to fix foreign key errors in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am using Ubuntu on Virtualbox. I’m trying to write my SQL for a database however whenever I create one with a Foreign Key it always returns an error

> CREATE TABLE Vehicles (Vehicle ID int, Vehicle Type VARCHAR(255), Model VARCHAR(255), Engine Size float, Condition VARCHAR(255), Price float, PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle ID), FOREIGN KEY (Model) REFERENCES Models(Model));

Can you help me please? Below are my SQL table statements to create the Database so maybe there is an error in my code?

```
CREATE TABLE Models (
     Model_ID int NOT NULL,
     Manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Wheel_Drive_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Model_ID)); 

CREATE TABLE Customers (
     Customer_ID int NOT NULL,
     Customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Customer_Contact_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Customer_Address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Customer_Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)); 

CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
     Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
     Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Engine_Size float NOT NULL,
     Condition VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Price float NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (Model) REFERENCES Models(Model_name)); 

CREATE TABLE Enquiries (
     Enquiry_ID int NOT NULL,
     Vehicle int NOT NULL,
     Customer_ID int NOT NULL,
     Additional_information VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Enquiry_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (Vehicle_ID) REFERENCES Vehicles(Vehicle_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customers(Customer_ID)); 

CREATE TABLE Sales (
     Sales_ID int NOT NULL,
     Vehicle_ID int NOT NULL,
     Customer_ID int NOT NULL,
     Date_of_sale VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Sale_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Sale_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (Vehicle_ID) REFERENCES Vehicles(Vehicle_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customers(Customer_ID));
```

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: @stickybit - with the edit, I don't think it's a duplicate. Quotes are not part of the issue as asked.

Comment: It's generally best for a foreign key to reference the primary key of the other table, not some other column.

Comment: @EdwardBarnard I think he linked to that because you have to use backticks when column names contain spaces. But that's just one of the several problems in this code.

Comment: @barmar I've edited to change this so it is now correct with the _ in the spaces.

Comment: @EdwardBarnard: Well, they use identifiers with space, that needed backticks. But OK then there's also `Model` vs `Model ID` or `Model_ID`, so it's not the only problem and I retract the close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has spaces as part of the identifier, which is not allowed. For example (Customer ID) rather than (Customer_ID). That's true throughout your example code. Also, when working with foreign keys, be sure you have the same type, including signed/unsigned. If you are using utf8mb4, a varchar index is limited to 191 rather than 255, and you'll want your field referenced with a foreign key to also be an index. (This advice MIGHT be obsolete, depending on your version, but the spaces are a problem.)

Comment: Spaces are allowed, but you have to put backticks around the name, so they're generally not a good idea. But he's not consistent, he has `Model_ID` as the column name, but `PRIMARY KEY(Model ID)`. They have to be the same.

Comment: I've edited to change this so it is now correct with the _ in the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The column you reference has to have an index, but there's no index on the `Model_name` column in `Models`. You need to add:

```
INDEX (Model_name)
```

```
CREATE TABLE Models (
     Model_ID int NOT NULL,
     Manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Model_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Wheel_Drive_Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Model_ID)
     INDEX (Model_name));
```

I suggest you take the `Model_name` column out of `Vehicles`, and replace it with `Model_ID`. It's usually best to have foreign keys point to primary keys.

Comment: The model column has now been suitably renamed to Model_name - none of the instances of foreign keys work though?

Comment: Since the other foreign keys reference `Vehicles`, they'll get an error if you can't create this table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with this segment **FOREIGN KEY (Model) REFERENCES Models(Model));**

Model_ID is the primary key of your table Models, hence the statement segment should be  **FOREIGN KEY (Model) REFERENCES Models(Model_ID));**

Also, the foreign key should be the primary key of the reference table with the same data type. Your DDL for **Vehicles** should look like following

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
    Vehicle_ID int, 
    Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(255), 
    Model_ID int, 
    Engine_Size float, 
    Condition VARCHAR(255), 
    Price float, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Model_ID) REFERENCES Models(Model_ID)
);
```